# Create JSON with key value

Tags: php, json

So I want a JSON string that look something like that:

```
{"Madagascar": [
    {
        "year": 2000,
        "country": "Madagascar",
        "country_id": 847,
        "indicator": "Net Income - National Currency (millions)"
    },
]}
```

but my php script just outputs key/value like:

```
    {
        "year": 2000,
        "country": "Madagascar",
        "country_id": 847,
        "indicator": "Net Income - National Currency (millions)"
    }
```

how can I set the "Madagascar"-key in PHP?

EDIT: I tried it as below:

```
$post_filter = $_POST['time']; //seconds
$filter = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
$filter_ = $filter->modify("-$post_filter second");
$insert = "SELECT * FROM chat "
        . "WHERE date >='" . $filter_->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "'"
        . "ORDER BY date DESC";
$return = $sql->return_array($insert);
foreach ($return as $var) {
    array_merge($arr, array($var["id"] => $var));
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: You didn't think to show us the PHP?

Comment: Where's your PHP Script?

Comment: Before encoding your JSON, just create the structure as you want.  So if that object is stored in `$data`, then just do `$newData = array('Madagascar' => array($data));`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easily done, here is an example.

```
$myInnerArray = [
    "year"=>2000, 
    "country"=>"Madagascar, 
    "country_id":847, 
    "indicator":"Net Income - National Currency (millions)"
];
$outerArray = ["Madagascar=>$myInnerArray];
echo json_encode($outerArray);
```

In your new code, change:

```
foreach ($return as $var) {
    array_merge($arr, array($var["id"] => $var));
}
```

To:

```
foreach ($return as $var) {
    $arr[$var["id"]] = $var;
}
```

to assign an element for each row.

Comment: yeah, that would be it. But I want to save more than one array under "Madagascar"

Comment: @Snickbrack see edit above. array_merge makes a big flat array of all rows, you want a subarray for each row. Get it?